# Как решить алгоритмическую задачу?

Tags: алгоритм

Задано три массива LONG чисел A,B,C, предложить алгоритм поиска трех чисел a,b,c (по одному из каждого массива), таких что a+b+c=C, C- заданное LONG число,такая комбинация только одна, и каждое из чисел a,b,c встречается только один раз. Алгоритм должен работать за O(n^2) и использовать O(1) памяти.

Comment: @asper, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Задача не учебная. Просто интересно найти решение. Решение за O((n^2)*log n) тривиально и очевидно, но лучшее решение мне найти не удалось. Буду благодарен если кто то подскажет решение лучше, или хотя бы куда копать.

Answer (score 6):

Задача простая, алгоритм следующий. (Кто то придумал, назвать и массив и сумму одной буквой С - это гениально. Поэтому, что бы не путаться, в моем ответе массивы называются A, B, C, элементы этих массивов - a,b,c, а нужная сумма - S)

Вначале нужно отсортировать все массивы. Алгоритмы сортировки с квадратичной сложностью и константным использованием памяти существуют, та же пузырьковая сортировка.

А дальше следующий алгоритм. для каждого элемента в массиве А делаем следующее. В массиве B берем первый элемент и пробегаемся по массиву С в поисках подходящего элемента (или границы, если элемента нет). Теперь в цикле идем по массиву В в сторону увеличения элементов. Если сумма больше S, то индекс для массива С уменьшаем до тех пор, пока сумма не буден равной или меньше. Когда в массиве В или С упремся в границу - внутренний цикл завершается.

Считаем сложность - сортировать массив  3*O(n^2) => O(n^2), поиск - n * (n+n) => O(n^2). Суммарная сложность вписывается.

Comment: За квадрат можно обойтись совсем без сортировки: следующее большее значение отыскивается за линейное время в неупорядоченном массиве.